# Control appearance of warnings after they were once supressed

Tags: python, warnings

Consider this:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.filterwarnings("always", category=DeprecationWarning)
>>> warnings.warn("Hello", DeprecationWarning)
/usr/bin/bpython:2: DeprecationWarning: Hello
```

OK got a warning there.

```
>>> warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
>>> warnings.warn("Silence", DeprecationWarning)
```

No warning here.

```
>>> warnings.filterwarnings("always", category=DeprecationWarning)
>>> warnings.warn("Silence", DeprecationWarning) # why remain silent?
>>>
```

No warning here, but there *should* be a warning for all I see. The same happens if you remove the "ignore" filter on both python 2 and 3.

While in principle this should not be a problem, (unless there is another reason), I am creating this silencing warning somewhere without being aware of. This makes it hard to be certain that warnings are controlled within a given warning context.

**NOTE:** Inside a script this example works fine. However my original problem is maybe only similar to this example, so I doubt it is confined only to the interactive prompt. In the original problem I see no warning given even though the first filter in `warnings.filters` should match it with "always" (I checked that).

Comment: Do you want to [reset the warnings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.resetwarnings)?

Comment: @mgilson, basically yes, but it does not work... Basically I want to save and restore the warning context, and this makes it not work as I expect it to work.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are saying.  I see 2 warnings when I put this in a script.

Comment: @mgilson, yup, you are right inside a script I get the same, so this has to do with the interactive prompt, but that does not quite convince me...

Comment: You're quite correct, this does behave differently in a script compared to from the interactive prompt.  You should probably make that explicit in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I guess this specific question is actually answered by this [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue4180). Unfortunately that does not seem to actually be my problem, but that is a different thing...

In case anyone is interested... my original problem was simply due to forgetting that `warnings.filters` uses regular expression `re.match` and that requires the start of the string to match.

To avoid this issue when testing deprecation warnings for `function`

```
if hasattr(function, '__globals__'):
    if function.__globals__.has_key('__warningregistry__'):
        function.__globals__['__warningregistry__'].clear()
```

this helped at least in my case. (There one warning was ignored while testing of another and then this issue triggered during testing of the first ignored warning)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this hack! Only Python2 is affected.